# Azure Performance/ load testing

Tags: azure, load-testing, performance-testing

What is the Performance / Load testing process in Azure? Do we need to take prior approval from Microsoft for executing a load test in Azure environment?

Comment: This, unfortunately, doesn't fit here on SO. It's about Azure policies. Nothing to do with programming. That said: Just load-test your app like anywhere else. You're paying for your resources. Use them.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about approval processes for testing.

Answer (score 4):

This is covered pretty well by QinDian Tang of Microsoft Support in the article listed below.   I'll put in the relevant stuff here and link below to give him credit.

> "If you will be generating a large number of requests from external
>   resources, you may be considering the security impact of such
>   requests. You may be worried that Windows Azure will see the requests
>   as a Denial of Service (DoS) or Distributed Denial of Service (DDoS)
>   attack. A DoS or DDoS attack floods servers with requests that can
>   severely degrade their performance, or cause the failures at the
>   server or application level. Indeed, Windows Azure detects such
>   attacks and is handled at the infrastructure or platform level. If you
>   generate a large number of requests for your application, Windows
>   Azure will not detect them as Dos attacks. DoS attacks usually involve
>   malformed requests that specify incorrect source IP addresses, or
>   whose source never acknowledges the packets for such requests. Because
>   the load on your application will be from legitimate requests, Windows
>   Azure will not filter such requests."

Article - https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/f41bdf3b-35d1-4b33-b307-cb257197261e/connection-refused-during-cloud-service-smoke-test?forum=windowsazuremanagement .

Healy in Tampa